# Image size not updating after toolbar resize

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a `mat-toolbar` element which has a size of 150px, and upon switching to a different component I set its size to 70px, like so:

```
<mat-toolbar style="position: sticky;" [style.height.px]="appWideService.toolbarHeight" color="primary">
<img/>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in the different component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appWideService.toolbarHeight = 70;
}
```

The problem is with the image that is inside the toolbar.
It doesn't update its size when the toolbar changes its size.
The css is the following:

```
img {
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

It stays the same size.  It's a refreshing issue, since when I change the zoom of the browser, it suddenly updates the image size.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: you can try updating the image ```img``` field using javascript/angular like how you are updating the size of toolbar in similar way.

Comment: @shashikant But I don't want to change the img size, I want it to adjust in a responsive way.

Comment: make a script that will detect the change in toolbar accordingly it will change the img which u want to change

Comment: Please provide the image (in original dimensions) that is used and a more detailed markup snippet (maybe the compiled one). We cannot test solutions properly without more information about the assets.

Comment: Could you post the HTML that is generated by Angular? Just copy paste what you get from the Element Inspector so that we can check for errors. Additionally, you may have some CSS associated to the toolbar, not just the image, that would help diagnose too.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple one.

You have

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Instead use

```
object-fit: fill;
```

**cover**

The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while **filling the element’s entire content box.** If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the **object will be clipped to fit.**

**fill**

The replaced content is sized to fill the element’s content box. The entire **object will completely fill the box.** If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the **object will be stretched to fit.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: is this the exact code you use? Because this...

```
<mat-toolbar style="position: sticky;" [style.height.px]="appWideService.toolbarHeight" color="primary">
```

... will result in 
`<div style="position: sticky;" style="height=70px;" color="primary">` ?

I think you can only have 1 style attribute in your html element

end EDIT

You have set max-width at 70% so changing the height of the box won't change anything if the width is already at 70% as it will retain it's ratio.

Try to remove max-width and see if it updates correctly when changing the height.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `object-fit: cover;` for that 
In this your image will automatically be resized

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **position : realtive;** with object-fit :fill; style in css

```
                          or
```

try refreshing your toolbar with ChangeDetectorRef pckg (whenever you change container of toolbar)

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef){}

this.cd.detectChanges();
```